# View currently open websites in the background

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Is there a way to view what websites are currently open in a browser that doesn't require user interaction (ie. done in the background).

The only related command I know of is `netstat -abf`, but I've used this command and it doesn't list all the connections (only accurately lists 1 or 2 of the open tabs).

Is there perhaps a location where open tabs are listed in temporarily files? Or maybe a registry key?

I'm using both Chrome and IE, and hopefully there is a way that could be applied to both. A third party application would suffice if it could connect remotely.

Comment: Once displayed in the tabs, the websites are in general no longer "open" and there is no connection to detect. You would need a browser extension for that, actually two - for Chrome and IE. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, but the application must leave some sort of temporary file **somewhere** that can be read. This for live-monitoring my PC's usage while I'm away from it.

Comment: To clarify: the non-creepy, legal type of monitoring XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is stateless, meaning that once displayed by the browser, the websites/URLs are in general no longer "open" and there is no connection to detect.
The browser keeps the original URL as a property of the displayed document,
but to access that one would need a browser extension or a JavaScript program running inside the browser (of which you have two),
and the information is lost once the browser is closed.

To find out what your computer was doing while you are absent,
you could use a monitoring suite such as are described in the article
[Best Free Parental Filter](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-parental-Filter.htm) : Norton Safety Minder or K9 Web Protection.

Other network traffic monitoring tools are available such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/),
but which are somewhat too technical for the job.